# Suppress "File Not Found" in Batch File

Tags: batch-file, file-not-found

I was trying to run below bat file which gives me number of files present in a folder, i was getting the count as per the files but if there is no files i am getting "File Not Found"

Count is 0 and which is okay, but i want to suppress "File Not Found"

Script:

```
@echo off

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

@echo off

set c2=0

echo Folder,NoOfFiles

for  /f "tokens=*" %%x in ('dir /s /a /b "D:\Flow\Flow1\Flow2\Flow3\NGR*.txt"') do set /a c2+=1

echo.NGR,!c2!
```

Result:

> Folder,NoOfFiles
>
> File Not Found
>
> NGR,0
>
> Press any key to continue . . .

I was trying to use 2>nul but that was also not working

Can someone please help me to get the solution, what can be done here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try with :

```
for  /f "tokens=*" %%x in ('dir /s /a /b "D:\Flow\Flow1\Flow2\Flow3\NGR*.txt" 2^>nul') do set /a c2+=1
```

Comment: Worked Fine :) Thanks :) could you please help me to understand why we use "^"?

Comment: @RishabhBhargav - because you are using another command you need to escape the redirection symbol `>` with the caret. As the redirection has a higher priority than for it first need to be parsed as a string and then executed.

Comment: Thanks!!!!!!!!!! 2^>nul helped for me